# Increment all regex matching numbers throughout an HTML file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a bunch of HTML files that have anchors structured like:

```
<a href="/src/pkg/target/somefile.txt?s=5424:5465#L217">LinkName</a>
```

I'm running the files through sed to convert the links into this structure:

```
<a href="//domain.org/a/b/somefile.txt#cl-217">LinkName</a>
```

The last piece of the puzzle that I'm trying to solve is that I need to increment the numbers within the anchor by 10:

```
#L217    -> #L227    // first link
#cl-217  -> #cl-227  // transformed link
```

So the final version of the above example link would be:

```
<a href="//bitbucket.org/juztin/config/src/tip/din.go#cl-227">LinkName</a>
```

---

I've gotten close =/

```
awk 'gsub(/#cl-[0-9]+/, "#cl-ABC")') # just can't get the incremented match in ABC
```

This one works, but only once, or once per line:

```
awk '{n = substr($0, match($0, /[0-9]+/), RLENGTH) + 10; sub(/[0-9]+/, n); print }
```

*(* I don't have gawk, or gnu sed)*

Comment: The examples you have shown aren't very clear. Even the links are different. Can you please show your initial input and expected output keeping sure its the same link?

Comment: @Justin Please check my answer, I've tested it with a couple of html files and it works like a charm (it took me a while because of the variables inside the sed regex), hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**1-** Create a file named `replace.sh`

```
for file in /path/to/files/*.html; do
while read line; do
    name=$line
    [[ $line =~ '<a href=".*?#L(.*?)">LinkName</a>' ]]; 
    match=${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
    replace=$((${BASH_REMATCH[1]} + 10));
    perl -i -pe 's!<a href=\".*?#L'$match'\">LinkName</a>!<a href=\"//domain.org/a/b/somefile.txt#cl-'$replace'\">LinkName</a>!g' $file
done < $file
done
```

**2-** `chmod +x replace.sh`
**3-** `./replace.sh`

Comment: Does this work when multiple links exist within a single line? (haven't tried it yet, don't have a working perl the machine)

Answer (score 0):

In POSIX shells you can use [`let`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/korn_shell_arith_eval.htm) to compute. First get *only* the number into a variable, then `let my_var++` to increment it.

On the other hand, I'm morally obliged to warn you that manipulating HTML with shell scripts is a maintainability disaster waiting to happen. Python, JavaScript, XSLT or Java would all do a much better job.

Comment: I'm only using this once, after some source code/comments have been updated, for HTML documentation generation by a tool. I've got everything I need in a script, and was trying to avoid using some language just for this one little thing =(  Thx for the info on `let`.